# How to deploy my elastic container registry and elastic container service in same stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am creating an AWS stack using their CDK language.

The stack will include a Fargate service to deploy a container image.  That image will be built and deployed to an Elastic Container Registry using Gitlab CI/CD pipelines.

However, this creates a chicken-egg problem.  I can't build my AWS stack all in one go, because the Fargate service depends on the image deployed to the container registry, but I can't deploy an image to the container registry until I have created the registry.  Currently, my workflow is to 1) create the registry manually, 2) deploy the image to the registry somehow, 3) build the rest of the stack with CDK.  It would be really awesome if I could create my whole stack with CDK, *including* the container registry.

Is it possible to create both my container registry and my Fargate service in the same cdk build/deploy?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can have two different stacks to create ECR repo and ECS cluster.

In your main file of cdk, define 2 stacks. develop the cdk code for ECR repo in stack_1 and develop the code for ECS cluster in stack_2.

Then Synth and deploy both the stacks in Stack_1 and Stack_2 order.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import aws_cdk as cdk


from appdeploy import Ecrrepo
from appdeploy import Ecscluster

app = cdk.App()
Ecrrepo(app,'ECR-REPO')
Ecscluster(app,'ECS-CLUSTER')  
app.synth()
```

Comment: The problem is that the newly created repo won't have any images in it.  So my fargate service can't deploy, because it wants to pull an image out of an empty repo.